# Can't resolve all parameters for Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use Storage service into my Ionic2 component.

I am getting following error on running `ionic serve`  
[image]

Please find below the code snippet:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private storage: Storage,
    private homeService: HomeService) {
    var context = this;
    storage.ready().then(() => {
      context.loadItems();
    });
  }

 loadItems() {}
}
```

Comment: can you show code and what you tried ?

Comment: Added the code now.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage/issues/71

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788623/local-storage-in-ionic-2-error same issue?

Comment: solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42788912/2505556 worked for me

Comment: Thanks guys. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42788912/2505556 helped me as well.