# Local storage in ionic 2 error

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2

I try to use this in my Ionic 2 application :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/storage/

I already run

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save
```

and

```
npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Successfully.

And when I tried to add Storage in my app.module.ts, I had this error :

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?).
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:127193:27)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11660:16)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27183:31)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27058:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27046:21)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27288:40)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27246:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27213:19)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:26897:50)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:72991:64)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:72951:52)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:72917:21)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:52753:25)
```

I don't understand how I have to do to solve it.

My app.module.ts :

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
...

providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    PData,
    PBackground,
    PTranslate,
    Storage
  ]

...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Ionic 2.2.0, it's recommended to use @ionic/storage version 2.0.0. Configuration in app.modules.ts has changed since the previous version. The error occurs if you haven't changed everything in the right way.

In app.modules.ts do following changes:

1. Remove Storage from providers
2. Change import statement:

   from: `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';`

   to: `import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';`
3. Add the following to the imports array:

   `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()`

The import array should look like below:

```
imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
],
```

NOTE: Do not make any change in imports of Storage in any other files.

Comment: Perfect thanks ! It will be better if they update the documentation ! ^^'

Comment: @V.Pivet they did!! Docs exist to be read lol You can take a look at the changes related to Storage [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#ionic-storage) and [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0). In the changelog they say **explicitly**: `Note: If you are using ionic-storage, you need to update it to 2.0.0 or you will run into an error similar to this: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?, ?).. For more information, see the Storage Documentation.`

Answer (score 0):

Your **app.module.ts** should look like,

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export function provideStorage() {
  return new Storage(['sqlite', 'websql', 'indexeddb'], { name: 'database_name' });
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: Storage, useFactory: provideStorage }, Storage
  ]
})
```

You have to use **set()** and **get()** methods to store and retrieve data in your pages. Have a look at [Ionic 2 Storage Tutorial Blog with example video](http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/mobile/storage-ionic-2). Hope this helps