# Ionic2 Error: "No provider for Storage"

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

After reading everything I could find, and failing, I must ask here:

I am trying to use ionic2's Storage, just like the doc tells me to,

doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

here is my Code:

app-module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    import { Intro } from '../pages/intro/intro';
    import { Checklist } from '../pages/checklist/checklist';
    // import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import {IonicStorageModule} from '@ionic/Storage';
    import { Data } from '../providers/data';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
    // import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        Intro,
        Checklist
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule,
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        Intro,
        Checklist
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        // Storage,
        //Http,
        Data
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}


data.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
// import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


@Injectable()
export class Data {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {
  }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.get('checklists');
  }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  save(data): void {
    let saveData = [];
    //Remove observables
    data.forEach((checklist) => {
      saveData.push({
        title: checklist.title,
        items: checklist.items
      });
    });
    let newData = JSON.stringify(saveData);
    this.storage.set('checklists', newData);
  }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

home.ts

```
// import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

// @Component({
//   selector: 'page-home',
//   templateUrl: 'home.html'
// })
// export class HomePage {

//   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

//   }

// }


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Checklist } from '../checklist/checklist';
import { ChecklistModel } from '../../models/checklist-model';
import { Data } from '../../providers/data';
import { Keyboard } from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  checklists: ChecklistModel[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: Data,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController, public platform: Platform) {
  }

  // constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public platform: Platform) {
  //   // this.checklists.push(new ChecklistModel("Noam", [1,2,3]));
  // }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  addChecklist(): void {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Checklist',
      message: 'Enter the name of your new checklist below:',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            let newChecklist = new ChecklistModel(data.name, []);
            this.checklists.push(newChecklist);
            newChecklist.checklistUpdates().subscribe(update => {
              this.save();
            });
            this.save();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  renameChecklist(checklist): void {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Rename Checklist',

      message: 'Enter the new name of this checklist below:',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            let index = this.checklists.indexOf(checklist);
            if (index > -1) {
              this.checklists[index].setTitle(data.name);
              this.save();
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  viewChecklist(checklist): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(Checklist, {
      checklist: checklist
    });
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  removeChecklist(checklist): void {
    let index = this.checklists.indexOf(checklist);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.checklists.splice(index, 1);
      this.save();
    }
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  save(): void {
    Keyboard.close();
    this.dataService.save(this.checklists);
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

The method that is supposed to get called and use the Storage is HomePage's `save()`.

I can't get that far, however, because before the page even loads, I get

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Storage!
>   Error at g (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7133) at
>   injectionError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1585:86) at
>   noProviderError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1623:12) at
>   ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3125:19) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3164:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3096:25) at
>   ReflectiveInjector*.get (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:2965:21)
>   at AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:254:82)
>   at AppModuleInjector.getInternal
>   (ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:481:44) at
>   AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:3929:44) at resolveDep
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11334:45) at createClass
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11202:32) at
>   createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:11028:37)
>   at createViewNodes (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12377:49) at
>   createRootView (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:12282:5)

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "quicklists: An Ionic project"
}
```

Since I did everything the doc said, please enlighten me - What is still missing that would cause the Storage not to be found

Thanks

Comment: In your app module, did you try moving the IonicStorageModule(forRoot) that's in your import statement to the providers array?  It seems like that error is pointing in that direction pretty hard.  Not sure if you need the forRoot part, but I'd try moving it out of the imports array and to the provider array.  Pretty sure that's where injectable things need to go.

Comment: @chairmanmow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788623/local-storage-in-ionic-2-error here it tells me to do what I did, Also the doc https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ states it belongs in imports

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I guess you followed the instructions.  I did notice one thing that might be involved, I noticed that you're importing 'import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';' one place, and your importing import { Storage } from '@ionic/Storage';... Note the S is capitalized in one of those.  Anyways, not sure how much I can help, but maybe that's a typo.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer used to get a lot of upvotes, and that stopped.

I can only assume this is due to version updates/bug fixes.

I suggest you update your angular before going forward with this solution.

---

Firstly you need to install: `npm install --save @ionic/storage`

The problem was in app.ts:

```
import {IonicStorageModule} from '@ionic/Storage';
```

Capital 'S' instead of non capital 's':

```
from '@ionic/Storage'
```

instead of:

```
from '@ionic/storage'
```

No idea why the compiler wouldn't catch that if it's a problem, but it didn't.

Thanks to @chairmanmow

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0 Run npm install @ionic/storage@2.0.0 --save --save-exact
Remove Storage from your providers in app.module.ts
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage' instead of import { IonicStorage } from '@ionic/storage' in app.module.ts
Add IonicStorageModule.forRoot() to the imports array in app.module.ts

Comment: **For me**, it was small `s` . It needs to be the same as present in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, I forgot to add the following in app.module.ts

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModul({ 
  ..., 
  Imports: [
  ...
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
],
```

Answer (score 10):

first do this npm install --save @ionic/storage

I managed to get this working using this ..

Inside `app.module.ts`

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

And then ...

```
providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, Storage]
```

And then in my `page.ts`

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

In the constructor ...

```
public storage: Storage
```

And then within the guts of my code ..

```
this.storage.get('date').then((value) => {
  // blah
});
```

Comment: Don't need to add `Storage` for `app.module.ts` file's `providers:` , which gives `Uncought error`. In my case I forgot to add `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';` at the `page.ts` component page. Thanks @Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I added this to `app.module.ts`:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

And, this to imports parts of the `app.module.ts`:

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
```

Answer (score 0):

2021 Ionic Storage v3
Angular:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Please make sure that you remember to add the main module in your `app.module.ts` file

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({ 
  ..., 
  Imports: [
    ...
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  ....
})
```

And also make sure that you are actually importing the actual `Storage` from `@ionic/storage-angular`.

```
constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
```

The above will seem fine and not show any errors even if you dont include

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular'
```

at the top of your file. I presume that is because of the native `Storage` available on the global `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

The injection as explained in the doc (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage), works well;

I first missed this information:
"this approach is meant for **usage in a single component**",
so, using it for both AppComponent and HomePage I did get this error, exactly.

I restored app.component.ts in its previous state, and all is fine now.
(works on ionic 6.20.1)